# How to shrink the frame size of mpeg2 transport stream using gstreamer

Tags: video, gstreamer, mpeg-2

I am trying to shrink the resolution of an mpeg2 transport stream video using gstreamer. I decomposed the stream into an audio portion and a video portion using tsdemux, add a capsfilter to shrink the video frame size, then combined the audio and video streams using tsmux. It failed with an error :

> “received from element udpsrc: Internal data flow error. Debugging
>   information: gstbasesrc.c(2948): gst_base_src_loop ():
>   /GstPihomerun-pipeline/GstUDPSrc:udpsrc: streaming task paused, reason
>   not-negotiated (-4)”

It even failed without adding the capsfilter.

The problem seemed come from composition in tsmux, the compatible sink pad in
tsmux couldn’t be generated because it came out the error
 "tsmux_pad_added handler: get sink pad failed”
I appreciate if any expert can provide help information on how to use the tsmux, or information how to change the transport stream  frame size.

The following is the code:

```
void demux_pad_added_handler (GstElement *src, GstPad *new_pad, HDHRElements *data) {
    GstPadLinkReturn ret;
    GstPad *sink_pad = NULL;
    GstCaps *new_pad_caps = NULL;
    GstStructure *new_pad_struct = NULL;
    const gchar *new_pad_type = NULL;
    GstStateChangeReturn scret;
    g_print("Received new pad '%s' from '%s':\n", GST_PAD_NAME (new_pad), GST_ELEMENT_NAME (src));

      /* Check the new pad's type */
    new_pad_caps = gst_pad_get_current_caps (new_pad);
    new_pad_caps = gst_pad_get_current_caps (new_pad);
    new_pad_struct = gst_caps_get_structure (new_pad_caps, 0);
    new_pad_type = gst_structure_get_name (new_pad_struct);
    if (g_str_has_prefix(new_pad_type, "audio")) {
       sink_pad = gst_element_get_static_pad(data->audioqueue1, "sink");
    }
    if (g_str_has_prefix(new_pad_type, "video")) {
        sink_pad = gst_element_get_static_pad(data->videoqueue1, "sink");
    }
    new_pad_struct = gst_caps_get_structure (new_pad_caps, 0);
    new_pad_type = gst_structure_get_name (new_pad_struct);
    if (g_str_has_prefix(new_pad_type, "audio")) {
        sink_pad = gst_element_get_static_pad(data->audioqueue1, "sink");
    }
    if (g_str_has_prefix(new_pad_type, "video")) {
        sink_pad = gst_element_get_static_pad(data->videoqueue1, "sink");
    }
    if (sink_pad != NULL) {
        if (gst_pad_is_linked(sink_pad)) {
            g_print("tsdemux pad ('%s') sink pad already linked (ignoring)\n",new_pad_type);
        } else {
            ret = gst_pad_link(new_pad, sink_pad);
            if (GST_PAD_LINK_FAILED(ret)) {
                g_print("tsdemux pad ('%s') but link failed.\n", new_pad_type);
            } else {
                g_print("tsdemux pad ('%s') link succeeded.\n", new_pad_type);
                scret = gst_element_set_state (data->pipeline, GST_STATE_PLAYING);
                if (scret == GST_STATE_CHANGE_FAILURE) {
                    g_printerr ("Unable to set the pipeline to the playing state.\n");
                }
                GST_DEBUG_BIN_TO_DOT_FILE_WITH_TS((GstBin*) data->pipeline, GST_DEBUG_GRAPH_SHOW_ALL, "newpad");
            }
            gst_object_unref(sink_pad);
        }
    }
    if (new_pad_caps != NULL) {
        gst_caps_unref(new_pad_caps);
    }
}

void tsmux_pad_added_handler (GstElement *mux, GstPad *pad, HDHRElements *data) {
    GstPad* sinkpad;
    g_print ("tsmux %s [linking] %s  ", gst_pad_get_name(pad), gst_element_get_name(mux));
    if((sinkpad = gst_element_get_compatible_pad (mux, pad, NULL)) == NULL) {
        g_printerr("tsmux_pad_added handler: get sink pad failed\n");
        return;
    } else {
        g_print("tsmux_pad_added handler: get sink pad succeeded\n");
        if (gst_pad_is_linked(sinkpad)) {
            g_print("tsmux sink pad %s already linked (ignoring)\n", gst_pad_get_name(sinkpad));
        } else {
            GstPadLinkReturn ret = gst_pad_link (pad, sinkpad);
            if(ret != GST_PAD_LINK_OK){
                g_printerr(" tsmux link failed [return code]:%d\n", ret);
            }else{
                g_print("tsmux link successful: %s to %s\n", gst_pad_get_name(pad), gst_pad_get_name(sinkpad));
            }
        }
        gst_object_unref (sinkpad);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    HDHRElements myelements;
    GstBus *bus;
    GstMessage *msg;
    GstStateChangeReturn scret;
    unsigned short gstdport;
    char *end;
    GMainLoop *loop;
    struct in_addr remote;
    GstCaps *caps;
    inet_aton(arg[1], &remote);
    gstdport = strtol(argv[2], &end, 10);

    /* Initialize GStreamer */
    gst_init (&argc, &argv);
    myelements.udpsrc = gst_element_factory_make("udpsrc", "udpsrc");
    myelements.rtpmp2tdepay = gst_element_factory_make("rtpmp2tdepay", "rtpmp2tdepay”);
    myelements.tsdemux = gst_element_factory_make("tsdemux", "tsdemux");");
    myelements.rtpmp2tpay = gst_element_factory_make("rtpmp2tpay", "rtpmp2tpay");
    myelements.tsmux = gst_element_factory_make("mpegtsmux", "tsmux");
    myelements.audioqueue1 = gst_element_factory_make("queue", "audioqueue1");
    myelements.videoqueue1 = gst_element_factory_make("queue", "videoqueue1");
    myelements.rtpmp2tpay = gst_element_factory_make("rtpmp2tpay", "rtpmp2tpay");
    myelements.udpsink = gst_element_factory_make("udpsink", "udpsink");
    myelements.pipeline = gst_pipeline_new ("hdhomerun-pipeline");
    gst_bin_add_many (GST_BIN (myelements.pipeline),
        myelements.udpsrc,
        myelements.udpsink,
        myelements.rtpmp2tdepay,
        myelements.rtpmp2tpay,
        myelements.tsdemux,
        myelements.tsmux,
        myelements.videoqueue1,
        NULL);
    g_object_set(G_OBJECT(myelements.udpsrc), "port", 1234, NULL);
    GstCaps *udpcaps = gst_caps_from_string("application/x-rtp, media=video, payload=33, clock-rate=90000");
    g_object_set(G_OBJECT(myelements.udpsrc), "caps", udpcaps, NULL);
    g_object_set(G_OBJECT(myelements.udpsink), "host", inet_ntoa(remote), NULL);
    g_object_set(G_OBJECT(myelements.udpsink), "port", gstdport, NULL);
    g_object_set(G_OBJECT(myelements.tsdemux), "program-number", 3, NULL);
    g_object_set(G_OBJECT(myelements.tsdemux), "name", "demux", NULL);
    g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(myelements.tsdemux), "pad-added", G_CALLBACK(demux_pad_added_handler), &myelements);
    g_object_set(G_OBJECT(myelements.tsmux), "name", "tsmux", NULL);
    g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(myelements.tsmux), "pad-added", G_CALLBACK(tsmux_pad_added_handler), &myelements);
    gst_element_link(myelements.udpsrc, myelements.rtpmp2tdepay);
    gst_element_link(myelements.rtpmp2tdepay, myelements.tsdemux);
    gst_element_link(myelements.audioqueue1, myelements.tsmux);
    gst_element_link(myelements.videoqueue1, myelements.tsmux);
    gst_element_link(myelements.tsmux, myelements.rtpmp2tpay);
    gst_element_link(myelements.rtpmp2tpay, myelements.udpsink);
    gst_element_set_state (myelements.pipeline, GST_STATE_PLAYING);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: did you ever find a solution to this?